# how to remove duplicate values in a XML file and keep the last one?

Tags: .net, python, xml, xslt, duplicates

I need to suppress all duplicate values in an XML file and keep the final value (refer to the target file).

Kindly help, since I don't know if I should use xslt, python, or any .NET API

Here is the source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>old_value</title>
    <title>inbetween_value</title>
    <title>new_value</title>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

The expected target file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>new_value</title>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is an extremely simple (no explicit conditionals, no axes) XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cd/title[not(position() = last())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>old_value</title>
        <title>inbetween_value</title>
        <title>new_value</title>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
   </cd>
   <cd>
      <title>Hide your heart</title>
   </cd>
   <cd>
      <title>new_value</title>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: It's unclear if the OP wants to remove all duplicates or just the `title` duplicates. I think your code works only for the latter, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it works perfectly, but the first line is removed:               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Comment: @laurentngu: If you *really* need the XML declaration, replace the `<xsl:output/>` by: `<xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>`

Comment: @laurentngu: I updated my answer, so that now it produces the wanted XML declaration.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1 version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cd/*">
 <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever technology you want.  If your requirement is "For each `cd` element, keep only the last value for duplicate child element names," here's a LINQ to XML solution, assuming you have an `XDocument` named `oldDoc`:

```
var scrubbedDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("catalog",
    from cd in oldDoc.Element("catalog").Elements("cd")
    select new XElement("cd",
        from elementsGroupedByName in cd.Elements().ToLookup(e => e.Name)
        select elementsGroupedByName.Last())));
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing all duplicates you could keep a dict between tag names and elements. In Python with minidom:

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
</cd>
<cd>
  <title>Hide your heart</title>
</cd>
<cd>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <title>old_value</title>
  <title>inbetween_value</title>
  <title>new_value</title>
  <artist>Freddie Mercury</artist>
  <title>Don't stop me now</title>
</cd>
</catalog>"""

from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parseString(xml)

for cd in doc.getElementsByTagName("cd"):
  elements = {}
  for element in cd.childNodes:
    if element.nodeType is not minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
      continue
    if element.tagName in elements:
      cd.removeChild(element)
      print("Removed duplicated " + element.tagName)
    elements[element.tagName] = element

# doc.writexml(open("/path/to/file", "w"))
```